# matlab array create random consecutive ones

Tags: arrays, matlab, random, multidimensional-array, rows

I would like to create an 4-dimensional array with a random number of consecutive ones in each row. The ones should always start in the first column and end in a random column.
Example:

```
array(:,:,1,1) = [ 1 1 1 0 0 0;
                   1 1 0 0 0 0;
                   1 1 1 1 1 0;
                   ...         ]
```

One could do that with 3 for loops but it is inefficient:

```
array = zeros(n,n,n,n);
for i= 1:n
   for j = 1:n
      for k =1:n
         rows = ceil(n*rand());
         array(k,1:rows,j,i) = 1;
      end
   end
end
```

Can somebody find a better solution? Thanks!!

Comment: What's your target data size? Thousands/millions/billions of elements?

Answer (score 5):

**Simple and straight-up approach (might not be truly random though)**

```
rows = 8; %%// Number of rows
cols = 7; %%// Number of columns
ch3 = 3; %%// Number of elements in the 3rd dimension
ch4 = 2; %%// Number of elements in the 4th dimension

array = sort(round(rand(rows,cols,ch3,ch4)),2,'descend')
```

**Bsxfun approach (Much faster as shown in benchmark results below and truly random)**

```
%%// Sizes
rows = 8; %%// Number of rows
cols = 7; %%// Number of columns
ch3 = 3; %%// Number of elements in the 3rd dimension
ch4 = 2; %%// Number of elements in the 4th dimension

%%// Get a 2D array with every row starting with a one
rows2 = rows*ch3*ch4;
a1 = reshape(1:rows2*cols,rows2,[]);
col = randi(cols,[1 rows2]);
b1 = bsxfun(@plus,(col-1)*rows2,1:rows2)';%//'
out = bsxfun(@le,a1,b1);

%%// Rearrange those to 4D
a2 = reshape(out',[rows*cols ch3 ch4]);%//'
a3 = reshape(a2,cols,rows,ch3,ch4);
array = permute(a3,[2 1 3 4]);
```

**Benchmark results**

We are comparing the above mentioned two approaches along with Rody's approach.

```
Datasize I:
rows = 80;  %// Number of rows
cols = 70;  %// Number of columns
ch3  = 30;  %// Number of elements in the 3rd dimension
ch4  = 2; %// Number of elements in the 4th dimension

Results:
Elapsed time with SORT approach is:   0.0083445sec
Elapsed time with BSXFUN approach is: 0.0021sec
Elapsed time with RODY approach is:   0.0063026sec

Datasize II:
rows = 80;  %// Number of rows
cols = 70;  %// Number of columns
ch3  = 30;  %// Number of elements in the 3rd dimension
ch4  = 20; %// Number of elements in the 4th dimension

Results:
Elapsed time with SORT approach is:   0.07875sec
Elapsed time with BSXFUN approach is: 0.012329sec
Elapsed time with RODY approach is:   0.055937sec


Datasize III:
rows = 800;  %// Number of rows
cols = 70;  %// Number of columns
ch3  = 30;  %// Number of elements in the 3rd dimension
ch4  = 20; %// Number of elements in the 4th dimension

Results:
Elapsed time with SORT approach is:   0.87257sec
Elapsed time with BSXFUN approach is: 0.17624sec
Elapsed time with RODY approach is:   0.57786sec


Datasize IV:
rows = 800;  %// Number of rows
cols = 140;  %// Number of columns
ch3  = 30;  %// Number of elements in the 3rd dimension
ch4  = 20; %// Number of elements in the 4th dimension

Results:
Elapsed time with SORT approach is:   1.8508sec
Elapsed time with BSXFUN approach is: 0.35349sec
Elapsed time with RODY approach is:   0.71918sec
```

In conclusion from these findings, `bsxfun` looks like the way to go, unless you want to process billions of elements, as memory-benchmark results produced by Rody's solution suggests.

Comment: (you already had my +1, so...+2!) Anyway, memory consumption was my primary concern, keeping performance acceptable. Compare mine and your `bsxfun` approaches with `profile -memory`, and look at the `peak memory` column; that's where the largest difference will be. Your first `bsxfun` creates a potentially huge `double` array, which I avoid. You'll indeed be faster, but only if you have the RAM.

Comment: A warning about all these solutions, they randomise each element not the number in each row, so the number of ones in each row will follow a normal distribution, not uniform distribution (as per the version presented by the OP) i used `hist(builtin('_paren',sum(array,2),:))` to quickly test

Comment: too late to edit but it is only the sort method which has this issue

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis I just increased the ch3 from `30` to `45` in `Datasize IV` and the bsxfun approach ran fine and your method ran out of memory. In any case, is the OP really looking for 200 million elements? Appreciate the +1 up!:)

Comment: @RTL Good finding!! So I guess `bsxfun` would be my choice.

Comment: @Divakar: Sometimes I don't care about the OP's exact situation :) Ran out of memory...interesting, can you explain that?

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis Spoke too soon. I was running your code right below mine without clearing out, so all together caused it to run of memory when executing yours.  About using more than 200M elements, at least I would think twice before doing so :)

Comment: @Divakar: Ah. Just got the same thing. I'm guessing you didn't clear your workspace before running my method? :p Anyway, see my latest edit.

Comment: @Divakar: You'd be surprised how often that occurs nowadays; big data is a big thing. Granted, it can often be prevented, but certainly not always. I for one find myself thinking a lot more in terms of how to handle the giant version of something efficiently, rather than just getting the absolute best performance for the small cases. And by giant, I mean efficiently storing a sparse matrix of several billion elements *in each direction*, and about solving linear systems with such beasts. Distributed storage and computing, great fun :)

Comment: @Divakar: As you have already noticed, I often get carried away, especially when it's late Friday afternoon :) So, sorry for spamming, but thanks for the entertaining discussion and solution :)

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis Great inputs there from you! I am getting into that arena myself. Don't worry, I am loving my stay on SO so far. Some very interesting problems asked and certainly smart guys around here :)

Comment: Hi folks! When benching these, it's a good idea to encapsulate them in functions so they all run in isolated workspaces. Prevents errors like that due to stuff left in a shared workspace. Plus, if you have data left around, that could skew your benchmark timings due to memory pressure or GC hits. Using functions gives you mostly-deterministic GC behavior. Here's how I structured this code when I tried to beat your solutions (and failed). (Nice `bsxfun` use!) http://pastebin.com/JXqNacHL

Comment: @AndrewJanke Thanks for taking time to put all these into one for benchmarking! I might actually use the techniques used in it in future too.

Answer (score 2):

A "big-data" alternative:

```
rows = 80;  %// Number of rows
cols = 70;  %// Number of columns
ch3  = 30;  %// Number of elements in the 3rd dimension
ch4  = 200; %// Number of elements in the 4th dimension

%// number of 1's in each row. Select the appropriate class to make 
%// sure peak memory remains acceptably small
intClasses = {'uint8' 'uint16' 'uint32' 'uint64'}; 
maxSizes   = cellfun(@(x) double(intmax(x)), intClasses);
numOnes    = randi(cols, rows*ch3*ch4,1, ...
                   intClasses{find(cols <= maxSizes, 1,'first')});

clear intClasses maxSizes   

%// Loop through all rows and flip the appropriate number of bits
array = false(rows*ch3*ch4, cols);
for ii  = 1:numel(numOnes)
    array(ii,1:numOnes(ii)) = true; end

clear ii numOnes    

%// Reshape into desired dimensions
array = reshape(array.', cols,rows,ch3,ch4);
array = permute(array, [2 1 3 4]);

clear rows cols ch3 ch4
```

(You could also use a `sparse`, but MATLAB only supports `sparse` for data of type  `double`...In all probability, the logical array consumes less memory. If you're *really* desperate: the `numOnes` array alone contains sufficient information to retrieve either a 1 or 0; there's no need to construct the actual array. So, you could write a small wrapper class that implements the `subsref` in this way, basically, creating your own specific `sparse` that way :)

Note that this is a lot slower than Divakar's solution when the array is small. However, then the array sizes increase, this becomes progressively faster than Divakar's solution, with a lot smaller peak memory footprint.

**EDIT:** Divakar's `bsxfun` approach is the fastest of them all, however, it has O(N²) memory complexity. I.e., it only works if you can fit

```
`(cols-1)·rows²·ch3²·ch4² + (cols+1)·rows·ch3·ch4
```

(plus a few) 8-byte `double` values in your RAM, as opposed to just `cols·rows·ch3·ch4` 1-byte booleans for my method ^_^

As a simple comparison: re-running the same test as Divakar above, but within `profile -memory`:

Divakar's method:

[image: Divakar's method]

My method:

[image: Rody' method]

As you can see, my method's peak memory equals the size of the output array (~130MB), while the overall speed the doesn't really suffer all that much, whereas Divakar's method has a memory footprint of 10× the output size (~1.4GB).

Comment: Good inputs with the memory-benchmarking. I am guessing it's all because of the `bsxfun` with it's JIT. If so, it's good I guess, because it indicates that it's using more of memory resources to compute something quicker than otherwise, until hit by memory limits. Maybe in future `bsxfun` would automatically re-arrange it's inputs to use some internal looping to account for system resources available, because it's doesn't look it is? Would be nice!